# Calculating eigenvalues (Schrödinger stationary states)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

I'm trying to determine the stationary states and the corresponding energies.

My system has an angular momentum that is given by quantum number $l=1$, and the eigenvectors to $L_z$ are given as $|+1\rangle,|0\rangle,|-1\rangle$ and form a base. (thank you for the input @ZeroTheHero)

$$|+1\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},|0\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},|-1\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

The Hamiltonian is
$$H = \frac {\hbar w}{\sqrt2} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &0\\ 
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

When calculating the eigenvalues (energies) of the stationary states, I first conclude that the hamiltonian eigenvalues should be identical to those of $L_z$. This would mean that I can write

$$ |n\rangle=\psi _{n} $$
$$H \psi_n (x) = E_n\psi_n (x)$$

So for $\psi_{+1}$, I would get

$$ H \psi_{+1}=\frac{\hbar w}{\sqrt 2} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &0\\ 
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \frac{\hbar w}{\sqrt 2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} =  E_n \psi_{+1}$$

But this doesn't appear to give me the correct solution.

Comment: Most likely $\vert -1\rangle$ is actually $(0,0,1)^T$ and not $-(1,0,0)^T$.  To be complete:
$$
\vert 1\rangle \to (1,0,0)^T\, \quad \vert 0\rangle \to (0,1,0)^T\, ,\quad \vert -1\rangle \to (0,0,1)^T
$$ as these are the three basis states in your space.

Comment: I will also point out that you can recognize your $H$ as one of the angular momentum operators.  Thus, you can guess that the eigenvalues will be identical to those of $L_z$.

Comment: You need to start with a generic vector $\psi_{+1}=(a,b,c)^T$ and solve $H\psi_{m}=m\hbar \omega \psi_{m}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very confused about what you mean by all this $L_z$ stuff. I believe there is some confusion between a Hamiltonian (which is an **operator**) and the **matrix** representation of the Hamiltonian.

If your **Hamiltonian** is represented as a **matrix** (with respect to some basis) then the eigenvectors of the **matrix** are the eigenvectors of the **Hamiltonian** (stationary states) also written in that same basis. As in if we assume the matrix you give above is $H$ written in some arbitrary basis $\{|a\rangle,|b\rangle,|c\rangle \}$. The eigenvectors of this **matrix** are:

- $v_1 = \frac{1}{2}\{1,-\sqrt{2},1\} \quad$    corresponding eigenvalue: $-\hbar \omega$
- $v_2 = \frac{1}{2}\{1,\sqrt{2},1\} \ \ \ \quad$     corresponding eigenvalue: $\hbar \omega$
- $v_3 = \{1,0,-1\} \quad \ \ \ \ \ \ $                     corresponding eigenvalue: $0$

so the stationary states of the **Hamiltonian** would be:

- $|v_1\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \big( 1|a\rangle - \sqrt{2} |b\rangle + 1|c\rangle \big)$
- $|v_2\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \big( 1|a\rangle + \sqrt{2} |b\rangle + 1|c\rangle \big)$
- $|v_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( 1|a\rangle  - 1|c\rangle \big)$

So to answer your question, the states $\{|v_1\rangle,|v_2\rangle,|v_3\rangle\}$ are your stationary states once you replace the $\{|a\rangle,|b\rangle,|c\rangle \}$ with the basis that that Hamiltonian was given to you in.

If it was given to you in the $L_z$ basis $\{|+\rangle,|0\rangle,|-\rangle \}$ then your stationary states are:

- $|v_1\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \big( 1|+\rangle - \sqrt{2} |0\rangle + 1|-\rangle \big)$
- $|v_2\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \big( 1|+\rangle + \sqrt{2} |0\rangle + 1|-\rangle \big)$
- $|v_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( 1|+\rangle  - 1|-\rangle \big)$

Comment: what are your $\vert a\rangle, \vert b\rangle $ and $\vert c\rangle$?  Surely the Hamiltonian is an operator but can be written as a $3\times 3$ matrix in the space spanned by the three states with $\ell=1$.

Comment: thank you so much, this cleared a lot up concepts up for me! just one question, I see you've normalized your eigenvectors $|v_1 \rangle, |v_2 \rangle, |v_3 \rangle$, why is that? Is it necessary to normalize them?

Comment: Eigenvectors do not need to be normalized but when we are thinking of the eigenvector as being a quantum state then it technically should be.